# How to delete an element from an array with specific key from local Storage in ionic 4,angular 7

Tags: local-storage, angular7, ionic4, ionic-storage

I want to delete an object from an array stored in local storage. With     this.storage.remove(key); I can only remove the whole array.A solution i found says that i have to remove the whole array, and then save the new one without the element i want to delete.Is this the only way? Or can i just save a new array with the same key and the old one will me overwritten?

lets say this what i have in localstorage.

Key of the array: "My-Key"

Items of the array: "[{"title":"item1","content":"content 11"},
{"title":"item2","content":"content 2"}]"

Item to remove: {"title":"item2","content":"content 2"}

Comment: Local storage doesn't support partial updates. So the only way to remove a single element is, to load it, remove it and replace the whole array as described in the solution you've already found. To identify an item within your array, you should however introduce an id-field.

Comment: @MarkusS. i see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your problem:

```
function removeItem(item_title) {
localStorage.setItem(
    "My-Key",
    JSON.stringify(
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("My-key")).filter(item => {
            return item.title !== item_title;
        })
    )
);
}

removeItem("item2");
```

Also, since you are working with `localStorage`, I would like to recommend you this tiny JS library, which will make it much easier to work with `localStorage` as well as `sessionStorage` and some other things alongside:
https://github.com/tranclix/XJS

By using **XJS**, the above code will be like this:

```
function removeItem(item_title) {
x.jls(
    "My-Key",
    x.jlg("My-key").filter(item => {
        return item.title !== item_title;
    })
);
}

removeItem("item2");
```